# C# ComboBox (DropDownList) -- Difference between SelectedItem- and Text-Property to change current item?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a WinForms project, which contains a Form, which then contains a ComboBox-element.

That ComboBox-element is set to "Style: DropDownList", meaning that the displayed text inside the ComboBox can only be an item from its list OR `null`.

So if I want to change the currently selected item, I realized I can use both

`ComboBox.SelectedItem = "example"`

but also

`ComboBox.Text = "example"`

Is there any difference between those two? (Keep in mind that the ComboBox is a DropDownList!)

Comment: Please do **not** vandalize your posts.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any difference between those two? (Keep in mind that the ComboBox is a DropDownList!)

For this particular `ComboBox.DropDownStyle`, the anser depends on the **type** of the objects used to populate the combo box `Items` collection. If the combo box is populated with `string`s, there is no difference, if other type of object is used, they will **always** differ. For instance, if you populate it with some class objects, then `SelectedItem` will be an instance of that class, while `Text` will be either obtained from `ToString()` method of that class, or some property of the class if specified by [DisplayMember](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

In general, these properties have a different meaning, so use the one which is appropriate for what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

The `Text` property is used when the combo allows text to be entered.  `SelectedItem` refers to an item in the ComboBox list of Items.  If you allow text entry then it is possible `SelectedItem` does not refer to the current `Text` value, the inverse is true also, the `Text` value doesn't mean there is an item in the source items collection.

If your ComboBox doesn't allow free form text to be entered then you only need to use the `SelectedItem` property.